# playerID is deprecated, Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, gamekit

What replaces player ID?

```
- (void)lookupPlayers {

    NSLog(@"Looking up %d players...", match.players.count);
    [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:match.players withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error) {

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error retrieving player info: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            matchStarted = NO;
            [delegate matchEnded];
        } else {

            // Populate players dict
            self.playersDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:players.count];
            for (GKPlayer *player in players) {
                NSLog(@"Found player: %@", player.alias);
                [playersDict setObject:player forKey:player.playerID];
            }

            // Notify delegate match can begin
            matchStarted = YES;
            [delegate matchStarted];

        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: Is the compiler warning you that `playerID` is deprecated? According to the documentation it's only `GKMatch` `playerIDs` that is deprecated (but the docs could be wrong).

Comment: Sorry, I changed the playersID to players as that fixed the deprecated issue. The actual issue is incompatible pointer type sending 'NSArray<GKPlayer *> *' to parameter of type 'NSArray<NSString *> *_Nonnull'

Comment: I'd recommend starting a new question for that if you're stuck with it, just for clarity.